# Translation of a passage related to the crusades

Tags: sentence-translation, medieval-latin, history, latin-to-english-translation

I am a historian, and I came across a text from Bauldric of Dol, a medieval historian. This text is about the crusades. I have been unable to translate the following passage. Could someone here help me out?

> sicut heri et nudiustertius, seriatim procedere, nec eorum clitellariis dabatur saltem repere posse
>
> *in* Bladricus Dolensis (c.1050–1130), *Historia Hierosolymitana*, [liber II](http://www.mlat.uzh.ch/MLS/xfromcc.php?tabelle=Baldricus_Dolensis_cps2&rumpfid=Baldricus_Dolensis_cps2,%20Historia%20Hierosolymitana,%20%20%202&id=Baldricus_Dolensis_cps2,%20Historia%20Hierosolymitana,%20%20%202&level=3&corpus=2&current_title=LIBER%20SECUNDUS.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This quote is from the [*Historia Ierusalem Baldrici Dolensis Archiepiscopi*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0GpHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PT537), Book 2 (pg. 1092 of  Migne, *Patrologia Latina*, CLXVI).

Your quote is only a fragment of the relevant sentence, which is likely why you are not able to make any sense of it. Here is the full sentence:

> Iter enim aggressi, gradiebantur rependo per montana, nimis aspera et scopulosa, per quae nec eorum phalanges poterant, **sicut heri et nudiustertius, seriatim procedere, nec eorum clitellariis dabatur saltem repere posse**, sed miserrime hi et illi praegravabantur, neque siquidem illis in angusto positis, aliud erat aliunde diverticulum.

Here is my translation: I have purposely separated the long sentence into shorter ones that are better adapted to English syntax.

> Having begun the journey, they advanced, crawling through the mountainous area, which was exceedingly perilous and craggy. Their battalions could not, **like yesterday and the day before, proceed in a file, nor was it possible for their pack animals even to crawl forward** through this area. Rather, they both were miserably encumbered, and there was not even an alternate route starting from elsewhere, since they were in a narrow area.

Two minor doubts on my part (comments welcome):

1. *phalanges* can be a "battalion" or also a "pole for carrying burdens" or "rollers for transporting war machinery" (see [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dphalangae)). It's very possible that the latter is intended.
2. I'm not entirely certain why *siquidem* is used: I am translating it as if it were *quidem*.

Comment: Thank you so much brianpck. I have a question about clitellariis. is it clitellariis means in English "bearing a pack-saddle" ? or is it pack animals true ? thank you

Comment: @user992 Yes, *clitellae, -arum* is a (plural) word for a pack saddle, and *clitellarius* means "bearing a pack-saddle." Here, the adjective is used as a noun, so "pack animals" would be the best translation: I guess you could call it metonymy.

Comment: thank you thank you so much for your help. it is very good translation.

Comment: @user992, if you think an answer (or a question) is good, please click the little up arrow to give a vote. I liked this answer and I voted for it, and I did the same for your question. Since you have asked this question yourself, you can choose your favorite answer by clicking the v-like button under the arrows. Voting in all forms is always useful.